# Proper way to handle _Layout needing access to scope in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using angular with an existing .NET MVC application. All of our .cshtml views are based include a partial _Layout.cshtml. We have a left sidebar generated in this _Layout. Depending on the web route the content in that left bar will change.

Problem is at one point I need get and put information into the sidebar in _Layout from $scope. The only way I know to do this is to go into the layout and wrap it with a ng-app. Something like so:

_Layout:

```
@(ViewBag.HotList != null ? " ng-app=hotListApp" : "")

if (ViewBag.Hotlist != null)
{

    <ul ng-controller="someCtrl" id="hotlist" class="hotlist">

    </ul>
}
@RenderBody()
```

But this is messy I have tons of pages. I would have to do this ng-app decision for most my pages. Is there a better way to separate this? How have others conquered this issue?

Comment: You'll have to bear with me here, I know nothing about angularjs.  It sounds like you want the layout to understand something in javascript ($scope) which is impossible while the view is being rendered to the client.  What is hotListApp?  Is that a controller or view (action/method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We put our ng-app at the body tag level:

```
<body id="ng-app" ng-app="app">
```

This way you can interact with any of your UI elements wherever they may live.  You may want to consider making your HotList into an Angular Directive.  You could then put attributes on your directive that you can interact with in your controller for the sidebar.  You directive could look like:

```
<div ng-controller="sidebarController"
    <HotList data="myData" />
</div>
```

The sidebarController would be responsible for retrieving the data and assigning it to the $scope variable "myData".  The logic inside your HotList controller would know how to render that data in an unordered list.

Comment: We are going to use the same solution you provided. Seems to be the best course of action.